# Insert Russian Language data into database from an array

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, encoding

My query looks like:

```
string str = string.Format("Insert into [MyDB].[dbo].[tlb1] ([file_path],[CONTENT1],[CONTENT2]) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}');", fullpath, _val[0], _val[1]);
```

Now when I insert data into database if `array _val[]` contains data in english language it insert correctly but when array contains data in Russian Language in database this show like `???????????????????????` 
Is there a way to insert data in Russian Language from an array.

Comment: What's the type of the database fields you're inserting to?

Comment: Wich database you use? What codepage choised for this fields?

Comment: DataBase version: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and fields are of nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use prepared statements and let the database driver insert the placeholders correctly (i.e. `SqlCommand` with parameters). Then the issue should go away (as well as any potential SQL injection problems).

As a quick fix in your case: Prefix the string literals you're inserting with `N`:

```
... values (N'{0}',N'{1}',N'{2}')
```

This causes the literals to be Unicode literals, not arbitrary-legacy-codepage ones and thus preventing the conversion from Unicode to the legacy codepage (which results in question marks for characters that cannot be represented).

Answer (score 2):

According to this (Archived) Microsoft Support Issue:

[**You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N** when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114081311/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/239530/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the datatype of columns `[Content1]` and `[Content2]` is `nchar`. You should convert the columns to `nvarchar` which is used to store unicode data.

Comment: datatype of columns is nvarchar not nchar

Comment: Then try checking the collation of your server/database. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must see  Database codepage at server. May be non-Unicode CP in database, but data from your app comes in Unicode format.